# asdf: No version is set for command elixir

Tags: elixir, config, asdf

I use asdf to install Erlang and then Elixir.

```
asdf install elixir 1.14.0-rc.1-otp-25
```

This results in:

```
asdf install elixir 1.14.0-rc.1-otp-25
```

And then ...

```
$ elixir
No version is set for command elixir
Consider adding one of the following versions in your config file at 
elixir 1.14.0-rc.1-otp-25
$ |
```

Which config file is this referring to?

Comment: Maybe you should make it your global default using `asdf global elixir 1.14.0-rc.1-otp-25`, or locally using `asdf local elixir 1.14.0-rc.1-otp-25` (which will create a `.tool-versions` config file in your current directory). Does it fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TLDR:

1. `asdf install elixir latest`
2. `asdf global elixir latest`

Or in your specific case: `asdf global elixir 1.14.0-rc.1-otp-25`

See the [Set a Version](https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html#_6-set-a-version) section of the asdf docs:

> ### 6. Set a Version
>
> `asdf` performs a version lookup of a tool in all `.tool-versions`
> files from the current working directory up to the `$HOME` directory.
> The lookup occurs just-in-time when you execute a tool that `asdf`
> manages.
>
> ::: warning Without a version listed for a tool execution of the tool
> will **error**. `asdf current` will show you the tool & version
> resolution, or absence of, from your current directory so you can
> observe which tools will fail to execute. :::
>
> #### Global
>
> Global defaults are managed in `$HOME/.tool-versions`. Set a global
> version with:
>
> `asdf global nodejs latest`
>
> `$HOME/.tool-versions` will then look like:
>
> `nodejs 16.5.0`
>
> Some OSs already have tools installed that are managed by the system
> and not `asdf`, `python` is a common example. You need to tell `asdf`
> to pass the management back to the system. The [Versions reference
> section](https://asdf-vm.com/manage/versions.html) will guide you.
>
> #### Local
>
> Local versions are defined in the `$PWD/.tool-versions` file (your
> current working directory). Usually, this will be the Git repository
> for a project. When in your desired directory execute:
>
> `asdf local nodejs latest`
>
> `$PWD/.tool-versions` will then look like:
>
> `nodejs 16.5.0`
>
> #### Using Existing Tool Version Files
>
> `asdf` supports the migration from existing version files from other
> version managers. Eg: `.ruby-version` for the case of `rbenv`. This is
> supported on a per-plugin basis.
>
> [`asdf-nodejs`](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-nodejs/) supports this
> via both `.nvmrc` and `.node-version` files. To enable this, add the
> following to your `asdf` configuration file `$HOME/.asdfrc`:
>
> `legacy_version_file = yes`
>
> See the [configuration](https://asdf-vm.com/manage/configuration.html) reference page for
> more config options.

Comment: I opted for Kiex in the meantime and will have to circle back to this in the future if need be. However, I will mark this as answered because it might just do it. Looks like it makes sense. Thank you, @Adam Millerchip

Comment: Important note for plugins besides Elixir: ASDF will look for `.tool-versions` starting from your working dir up to `$HOME`. So for certain tools/projects, it may make more sense to go to the project root and set a `local` version there, e.g., for Terraform.

Answer (score 0):

It is referring to the .tool-versions file. See similar post below:

https://elixirforum.com/t/error-when-checking-elixir-version/37965/5

Comment: Links are not welcome as answers on this site. Please consider either post this as a comment, or elaborating so that it would be a ready-to-go answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for reference.